# WiceGrid default filter on column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wice-grid

I am using the [WiceGrid](http://wicegrid.herokuapp.com/) gem (which is awesome!), however I am stuck on something relatively simple and can't seem to find anything in the documentation.

I want to have a default filter on a column. eg. A boolean column defined can have filtering options for Yes and No, but on first load the default filter might be set to No.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the conditions in the controller.
Here is the link: http://wicegrid.herokuapp.com/basics6

In the controller, there is something looks like this:

```
@grid = initialize_grid(

conditions: { you_filter: no }

)
```